# Laravel set a common validator for all date fields in the system

Tags: validation, laravel-5, model, request

I have different date fields in different models, I need to validate these date fields format on save of each model accordingly. is this possible?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Of course, you can. You just need to add this code below to your Model.

`public static $rules = [
 'date'=> 'reqired|date_format:MM:dd:YYYY' //if date is not required, ommite it
 ]`

You can use different formats for your date in your different Models like `MM:dd` etc. Hope this helps you.

> EDIT

To be able to use multiple `date` formats in a single validator You can define the multi-format date validation in your AppServiceProvider with the following code:

```
class AppServiceProvider extends ServiceProvider  
{
  public function boot()
  {
    Validator::extend('date_multi_format', function($attribute, $value, $formats) {
      // iterate through all formats
      foreach($formats as $format) {

        // parse date with current format
        $parsed = date_parse_from_format($format, $value);

        // if value matches given format return true=validation succeeded 
        if ($parsed['error_count'] === 0 && $parsed['warning_count'] === 0) {
          return true;
        }
      }

      // value did not match any of the provided formats, so return false=validation failed
      return false;
    });
  }
 }
```

You can later use this new validation rule like that:

```
'date' => 'date_multi_format:"Y-m-d H:i:s.u","Y-m-d"' //or any other format
```

Hope this helps, thanks.

Comment: I need to validate like 'dd/mm/yyyy' format. So gave it like  'date'=> 'reqired|date_format:d/m/Y' . But in this case it is restricting x/x/xxxx kind of dates. I want to take the both 'xx / xx / xxxx' and 'x / x / xxxx'

Comment: The 'date' validator takes only one date format as parameter. In order to be able to use multiple formats, you'll need to build a custom validation rule. And it's pretty simple. I am giving you the example